# Regex match string until whitespace Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, whitespace

I want to be able to match the following examples:

```
www.example.com
http://example.com
https://example.com
```

I have the following regex which does NOT match `www.` but will match `http://` `https://`. I need to match any prefix in the examples above and up until the next white space thus the entire URL.

```
var regx = ((\s))(http?:\/\/)|(https?:\/\/)|(www\.)(?=\s{1});
```

Lets say I have a string that looks like the following:

`I have found a lot of help off www.stackoverflow.com and the people on there!`

I want to run the matching on that string and get

`www.stackoverflow.com`

Thanks!

Comment: try this as your regex: `/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/`

Comment: do you want to match it only or need to validate as well.

Comment: just match, I need to do a string replace on it

Comment: Can you put a sample output for what you want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try

```
(?:www|https?)[^\s]+
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/wC5vM7/6)

sample code:

```
var str="I have found a lot of help off www.stackoverflow.com and the people on there!";
var found=str.match(/(?:www|https?)[^\s]+/gi);
alert(found);
```

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
    www                      'www'
   |                        OR
    http                     'http'
    s?                       's' (optional)
  )                        end of grouping
  [^\s]+                   any character except: whitespace 
                            (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
```

Comment: for Javascript you have to replace the `+` with a `*`, but that answer helped me alot! `/(?:www|https?)[^\s]*/ig` was my final regex

Comment: Use any one based on your requirement. `+` is used for **one or more** where as `*` is used for **zero or more**. I have tested it in Firefox. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your regex.

Use this:

```
((\s))(http?:\/\/)|(https?:\/\/)|(www\.)(?!\s{1})
                                          ^--- Change to negative lookaround
```

Btw, I think you can use:

```
(?:(http?:\/\/)|(https?:\/\/)|(www\.))(?!\s{1})

MATCH 1
3.  [0-4]   `www.`
MATCH 2
1.  [16-23] `http://`
MATCH 3
2.  [35-43] `https://`
```

Comment: That great and matches `www.` `http://` and `https://` but not until the next whitespace for example; `www.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do, but this should match any group of non-space characters not immediately preceded with "www." case insensitive.

```
/(https?:\/\/)?(?<!(www\.))[^\s]*/i
```

... [edit] but you *did* want to match www.

```
/(https?:\/\/)?([^\s\.]{2,}\.?)+/i
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, **to match any whitespace char, use `\S`** construct (in POSIX, you would use `[^[:space:]]`, but JavaScript regex is not POSIX compliant). Here are some common patterns with `\S`:

- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars

**Matching any text until *first* whitespace** can mean *match any zero or more chars other than whitespace*, so, the answer to the current OP problem is

```js
(?:www|https?)\S*
//            ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1noqFB/1). **This pattern will match up to the first whitespace or end of string**. If there *must* be a whitespace char on the right use

```js
(?:www|https?)\S*(?=\s)
```

The `(?=\s)` positive lookahead requires a whitespace immediately to the right of the current location.

Whenver there is a need to match until *last* whitespace you could match any zero or more chars that are followed with a whitespace, `\s`, pattern:

```js
/(?:www|https?)[\w\W]*(?=\s)/
/(?:www|https?)[^]*(?=\s)/
// Or even (for ECMAScript 2018+):
/(?:www|https?).*(?=\s)/s
```

The `[\w\W]`, `[^]` and `.` with `s` flag match any char including line break chars.